# Shuffle the list of Objects java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, shuffle

I have a list of words: `List<Word> words`

The bean `Word` is:

```
public class Word {
    private String name;
    private String meaning;
...
}
```

I would like to shuffle the elements to have the following:

From:

```
{ name: "day", meaning: "giorno"},
{ name: "year", meaning: "anno"},
{ name: "hour", meaning: "ora"}
```

To:

```
{ name: "day", meaning: "ora"},
{ name: "year", meaning: "giorno"},
{ name: "hour", meaning: "anno"}
```

I've tried this but I think there is a more elegant solution:

```
private List<Word> shuffle(List<Word> words) {
        List<String> names = words.stream()
                                .map(word -> word.getName())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> meanings = words.stream()
                                .map(word -> word.getMeaning())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(meanings);

        words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        for(int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++) {
            words.add(new Word(names.get(i), meanings.get(i)));
        }

        return words;
    }
```

Comment: @michalk Please read the full question and non just the title :D

Comment: @Januson Please read the full question and not just the title :D

Comment: @NikNik Do you want in-place shuffling? I mean original list should be updated or you want a new list?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz it doesn't change that much for me so both solutions are valid

Comment: The `Word` class seems a bit useless, if you're going to constantly change the value of `meaning`.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm using the bean Word to store words.
I wanted to reuse the same bean for "quiz" purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in-place shuffling. For that, you don't need to create extra `Word` objects.

```
private void shuffle(List<Word> words) {
    List<String> meanings = words.stream()
            .map(Word::getMeaning)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(meanings);

    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        words.get(i).setMeaning(meanings.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever solution!

Comment: You could take this a step further by creating a wrapper list, like `class MeaningList extends AbstractList<String> implements RandomAccess { public String get(int index) { return words.get(index).getMeaning(); }
 public String set(int index, String newMeaning) { Word w = words.get(index); String old = w.getMeaning(); w.setMeaning(newMeaning); return old; }
 public int size() { return words.size(); } }` Then, you only need to pass it to the suffle method like `Collections.shuffle(new MeaningList());` and you’re done.

Comment: @Holger you're right. We can do that.

Comment: @NikNik If this answer helped you then consider accepting it.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz It helped me for sure and that's why I've upvoted. Let's wait a little bit to see if there are other ideas ;) (However, the people marked the question as duplicate (even if it's not) so now it's not possible to submit new asnwers anymore).

Comment: @NikNik yep that's true. Now new answers can't be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Without `zip` and with only in-place shuffle, your solution look pretty elegant. I would just refactor it a little bit:

```
ArrayList<Word> wordsCopy = new ArrayList<>(this.words);
Collections.shuffle(wordsCopy);
List<Word> result = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Word(words.get(i).name, wordsCopy.get(i).meaning))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is not an in-place solution. You are creating a new `List<Word>`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. If there is shuffle which doesn't change the original array, then it would be one line less. And immutable structures are always better in terms of readability.